# java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set

Tags: java, sql-server

Here I have attached my code, it shows the error like: 
 java.sql.SQLException:

Before start of result set what I am doing wrong here:

```
String qry = "SELECT * From register ";



stmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(qry);
rs =  stmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    String area = rs.getString("city");
    if(city.equals(area)){
        System.out.println("!!!!!!It matched: " + city);
        String qry2="select state from register where city='"+city+"'";
        System.out.println(qry2);
        stmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(qry2);
        rs =  stmt.executeQuery();
        String state=rs.getString("state");
        System.out.println("state: " + state);
        break;
    } else {
        //System.out.println("No match with: " + area);
    }
}
```

Comment: This JDBC code makes no sense.  You can't iterate over a ResultSet and change the value in mid stream.  What are you doing?

Comment: Duffy is right, you should make new query outside the old one.

Comment: What is `qry`?  Why is there an if on `area` when `area` should be part of the query WHERE clause?  Why a second query?  Can you update `qry` to join with the register table?

Comment: Agree with everything so far (you shouldn't be reassigning `rs` inside of an iteration over `rs`, you should have a `WHERE` clause in your SQL query instead of selecting everything.) And additionally, never, **never** use raw concatenation to build queries with values that come from ANY user (such as might come from a `city` column). You must, must, must use parameterization. Go research "SQL injection" to find out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second resultset is not required in your code. *State* and *City* both can be found in same resultset. You can use the following code:

```
String qry = "select * from register";
PreparedStatement stmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(qry);
             rs =  stmt.executeQuery();
             while (rs.next()) {
                 String area = rs.getString("city");
                 if(city.equals(area)){
                    System.out.println("!!!!!!It matched: " + city);
                    String state=rs.getString("state");
                    System.out.println("state: " + state);
                    break;
                 } else {
                    //System.out.println("No match with: " + area);
                 }
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a new ResultSet object for query2 inside the query1 result set loop.

```
String qry2="select state from register where city='"+city+"'";
System.out.println(qry2);
stmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(qry2);
ResultSet rs2 =  stmt.executeQuery();
String state=rs2.getString("state");
```

But generally it would be a better use of JDBC resources to iterate all the way through result set 1, collecting all the "city" values returned, and then loop through the "city" results calling query2 to get the "states" associated with the "cities" instead of they way you've showed.